# Вы хотели бы познакомиться с новыми людьми? Правильно или нет?

Tags: грамматика

Вы **хотели** **бы** познакомиться с новыми людьми?

Answer (score 1):

Без знания того, что именно вы хотели выразить, трудно оценить объективно. Но если оценивать исключительно с точки зрения стилистики, лексики и синтаксиса - правильно.